# Sorting not working for MUI Data Grid: Data Grid sortComparator giving undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to sort data with nested values in a data grid
But getting undefined on sortComparator of Data Grid Columns

Code:
Column Data Setup:

```
   { 
    headerName: 'Title',
    field: `${this.props.type}.title`,
    width: 500,
    type: "string",
    renderCell: (valueReceived) => this.getImageorVideoLogo(valueReceived.row),
    sortComparator: this.titleSorting
   }


titleSorting = (a,b)=>{
       console.log(a);
       console.log(b);
}
```

Data Grid:

```
               <DataGrid
                    rows={rowsDataGrid}
                    columns={columnsDataGrid}
                    components={{
                        Toolbar: this.getSearchTextField
                    }}
                    pageSize={5}
                    rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
                   
                    // checkboxSelection
                    // disableSelectionOnClick
                    autoHeight
                />
```

Problem both console print undefined
Ideally it should give either the whole row a and row b or atleast row a column data and row b column data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with a custom field and the valueGetter param :

```
{ 
    headerName: 'Title',
    field: "CustomField,
    valueGetter: () => this.props.type.title,
    width: 500,
    type: "string",
    renderCell: (valueReceived) => this.getImageorVideoLogo(valueReceived.row),
    sortComparator: this.titleSorting
}
```

And add a comparison algorithm in your comparator function such as

```
const titleSorting = (a, b) => {
   a - b;
}
```